# youtube chromeless scaling player

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

Does anyone know how can I make a **chromeless** player scaling based on browser size like this: http://lab.veille.jp/elastic-youtube-player/

I tried using this http://tutorialzine.com/2010/07/youtube-api-custom-player-jquery-css/
and make the player scalable with jQuery, but it suffers from performance loss and doesn't make the video rescale properly when the window gets resized.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "cromeless" player?

Comment: sorry misspelled "chromeless" which is the player without chrome youtube controls bar http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html

Comment: this url http://lab.veille.jp/elastic-youtube-player/ does not work for me...

Answer (score 1):

You can use dirrect jquery API in order to change size of player

```
$('#video_quwebVjAEJA').height('50px')
$('#video_quwebVjAEJA').width('50px')
```

where '#video_quwebVjAEJA' - id of `object` tag

Please note that these new values must be less than native from attributes "width" and "height". So you can set maxSize in that one.